# HTTPS tunnel inside SSH using JSch

Tags: java, http, ssh, https, jsch

I'd like to communicate with HTTPS server via SSH using Java library JSch. Streamforwarding example on library website is easy to use, even on SO is code with that ([Java JSch create channel to access remote server via HTTP(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791014/java-jsch-create-channel-to-access-remote-server-via-https)).

Problem is when I want use `HttpsURLConnection` class to communicate via HTTPS. For instance to make `GET` request I try to operate on `InputStream` from `Channel` class (from JSch) and `InputStream` from `HttpsUrlConnection`.

Comment: Https through SSL is possible in general, however it will end up in a certificate validation error as the server certificate does not match the server name (e.g. server name www.example.org forwarded to localhost). Therefore you have to implement and use a custom `HostnameVerifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward a local port via the SSH connection to the remote HTTP server port:

```
Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "ssh.example.com");
// ...
session.connect();

int forwardedPort = session.setPortForwardingL(0, "http.example.com", 80);
```

Now you can connect `HttpsUrlConnection` to `http.example.com` and port `forwardedPort`.